# Change Kubernetes Service Name Without Removing It

Tags: kubernetes

Suppose in my microservice architecture, I have a microservice that receives API calls, and sends the required RPCs to other microservices in order to respond the calls. Let's call it `server`.

In order to be exposed to outside world, I have a `NodePort` Service for this microservice named after its name (`server`).
Currently I am using RabbitMQ for my inter-service communications, and `server` is talking to other microservices via RMQ queues.

Now I want to deploy a service mesh and use gRPC for inter-service communications. So I need to create K8s Service for gRPC port for all of my microservices with their microservice name (including `server`). However, the K8s Service with name `server` already exists and I need to change the name of that `NodePort` in order to be able to create its gRPC Service, but K8s doesn't let me change the Service name. If I delete the `NodePort` and create another one with a new name, my application would be down for that couple of seconds.

Final question is, how can I achieve renaming this `NodePort` while having my application available to users?

Comment: What about creating a brand new NodePort service "server-renamed" (with the same selectors and everything as "server"), then change your microservices config to use it, once all is OK, remove "server" service and recreate it with the new required specs?

Comment: @AdamBarreiro Can we have multiple Services pointing to the same target port?

Comment: Well, it seems it's possible. I think problem is solved! Sometimes you're busy complicating things that these easy peasy solutions even don't come to mind. It'd be good if you write this as an answer so we can close the case.

Comment: Yep, I think the only difference will be the "nodePort" port exposed in the node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Create a brand new NodePort service "server-renamed" (with the same selectors and everything as "server")
2. Change your microservices config to use it and check all is OK
3. Remove the "server" service and recreate it with the new required specs.